# Map string to object/json and vice versa

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to find a more elegant way to read a string and parse the information into an object which i need to create a json response in a service between a cobol machine (the string side of this transaction) and a webservice that interacts with anyone else via json.

I need to translate a text stream into json and vice versa. I also need to keep the order and when i translate a json request into string format. The text stream may also contain multiple objects worth of data

This is a shortend version of a possible string:

```
"104208760010                              Lin            Manuel       mystreet 24                                 12345MyCity                  "
```

My current approach looks as follows. I created a config.json like this:

```
{
"companyid": {
    "bound": "right",
    "decimals": 0,
    "length": 2,
    "pos": 0
},
"customerid": {
    "bound": "right",
    "decimals": 0,
    "length": 6,
    "pos": 2
},
"fname": {
    "bound": "left",
    "decimals": 0,
    "length": 15,
    "pos": 42
}
}
```

which I read at program startup into an object. Then I created a method that reads an input and manipulates the string according to the config (get text information by position in the string and padleft/padright, trim).

If i want to translate json into this text format I hardcoded a StringBuilder that appends accordingly.

Now this is an approach that does work but isn't really maintainable as soon as bigger datasets are to be programmed. Is there an easier way?

Comment: simply use the existing tools in .NET : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data

Comment: I already use json.net to map my json to an object. My problem isn't the json part but the easiest solution to map all properties into a string with given (via config) parameters as to how to create this string (padding left/right, length etc.)